# Using jQuery AJAX requests - POST to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a cross-platform application using HTML, CSS, and jQuery/JavaScript. I am using AJAX requests to get data from a database, as well as posting data to a database. I have gotten the AJAX 'GET' request method to work. This is my 'GET' method (this is in a script I have on one of my HTML pages).

***GET method***

```
var outputHeader = $('#outputHeader');
var outputDes = $('#outputDes');
$.ajax({
    url: '/currentEvent.php',
    type: 'GET',
    //data: 'json',
    datatype: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data) {
        outputHeader.html("");
        outputDes.html("");
        for (var i in data) {
            outputHeader.append("<h2>" + data[i].Event_Name + "</h2>" + "<p>" + data[i].Event_Date + "</p>" + "<p>" + data[i].Event_Time + "</p>" + "<p>" + data[i].Event_Venue + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Organised by &nbsp" + data[i].Event_Organiser + "</p>");
            outputDes.append("<center>" + "<img src='" + data[i].Event_Image + "'/>" + "</center>" + "<p>" + data[i].Event_Description + "</p>")
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        outputHeader.html('<p>There was an error loading the data.</p>');
        outputDes.html('<p>There was an error loading the data.</p>');
    },
});
```

It is the 'POST' method that is troubling me. This is the code I have for the 'POST' method (this is in a script I have in one of my HTML pages).

***POST method***

```
var urlID = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: '/currentEvent.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'urlID=' + urlID,
    datatype: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
});
```

The AJAX request is posting to this .php page.

***currentEvent.php page***

```
        $eid = $_POST['urlID']];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Event WHERE Event_ID = {$eid}";
        $getData = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query );
        if ($getData === false) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }           
        $records = array();

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getData, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
            {
                $records[] = $row;
            }
        //echo json_encode($getData);
        echo json_encode($records);
```

When I run the HTML page (I am using a server), it doesn't set "$eid" as 1. I have the 'POST' method before the 'GET', because I have to post the id to the php page so that it can run the query and return the data back to the application. The result is an array of variables in the 'GET' method being undefined. I would post a picture, but I cannot because I am new.

I have tried the solutions that were suggested by other users, but it didn't work. I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to developing in jQuery and JavaScript, so it is taking me a while to understand it. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling the GET function after the POST function? Are you using these values ? Maybe your problem solves with a `$.Deferred`. But with this information is impossible to see. Please, post all your relevant code, function declarations, etc

Comment: I am calling the POST function before the GET function. Where should I use `$.Deferred`?

Comment: Deferring object allows you to execute an action after another action is finished. This is the most common problem in new users that starts to develop with asynchronous calls. See more in the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score -1):

From what I know, in post you need to set the request header of "content-type" to "multipart/form-data". You would do this like so:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/currentEvent.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: 'urlID=' + urlID,
         datatype: 'text',
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
         },
         success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
         },
      });
```

Hope this helps,

Awesomeness01

Comment: I have implemented this, but when I run the web page, it still says the variable is undefined...